# sort redis output from terminal for use with comm command

Tags: sorting, unix, redis, comm

I'd like to use unix's `comm` command to compare different results from `redis`.

Redis outputs will be strings separated by new lines, for example:

```
# redis-cli smembers set_1
1) "term 1"
2) "term 2"
3) "term 3"

#redis-cli smembers set_2
1) "term 2"
2) "term 4"
```

so I was trying something like:

`comm -12 <(sort redis-cli smembers "set_1") <(sort redis-cli smembers "set_2")`

But there's clearly something wrong here, I think this sort command only works with actual files, not outputs.

So is it possible to use `comm` to sort the output of redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there's clearly something wrong here

Yes, `sort` would expect filenames as arguments (in addition to sort options).

You can say:

```
comm -12 <(redis-cli smembers "set_1" | sort) <(redis-cli smembers "set_2" | sort)
```

Note that depending upon the desired sorting for the output of `redis-cli ...`, you might want to pass arguments to `sort`.  Options such as `-k`, `-s`, `-t` might help.